# Characterization of greedy TSPs?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, traveling-salesman-problem

Define a *greedy* tour of a set $S=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$
as produced by selecting the $i$-th point $p_i$ to start, and then connecting to the nearest neighbor $p_j$ to $p_i$, then to the nearest neighbor to $p_j$ (excluding $p_i$), and so on, finally closing back to the start $p_i$.
So there are $n$ possible greedy tours. Assume general position so there are no ties.

My question is:

> When is the shortest greedy tour equal to the
> Euclidean TSP? Is there any characterization,
> or at least sufficient conditions on $S$, such that the shortest greedy tour is the TSP?

For example, below shows the optimal TSP for a $50$-point set, and one of the
$50$ greedy tours that fails to achieve the TSP.

[image: 50 pts]

   <sup>Optimal tour $62.5$ compared to $77.4$, greedy starting at $(8.6)$.</sup>

Whereas every greedy tour of this set of points on an ellipse is also the TSP tour.

[image: Ellipse]

   <sup>$|S|=18$.</sup>

Perhaps the "local feature size" or the "reach of a manifold"
can be used to quantify conditions on $S$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms for some discussion of the nearest neighbor approach to TSP. (Note that the minimum spanning tree-based algorithm is also quite simple, but does better.)

Comment: Thanks, @SamHopkins. I am less interested in the algorithmic issues as I am in understanding the shape of the point sets that can be greedily TSP'ed, so-to-speak.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, was just a comment. My (random) guess would be that it would be hard to describe the TSP instances where nearest neighbor is optimal.

Comment: any set of points that samples a piecewise smooth closed curve dense enough will do where *dense enough" means that the Euclidean distance between neighboring points is e.g. smaller then the minimum distance betwen a point of the curve's Voronoi diagram to a point on the curve. Actually twice that distance may suffice.

Answer (score 1):

<s>A simple "a posteriori" criterion is that on the optimal tour the distances to the tour-neighbors is smaller than that to any of the other vertices.

Convexity alone doesn't suffice as the example of ellipses with sufficiently high excentricity demonstrates.</s>

Another, "a priory" criterion *may* be that the maximum weight matching of every $K_4$ induced by 4 vertices of the TSP instance consists of the two longest edges of that subgraph.

Ruminating further, a general sufficient condition is that the Minimum Spanning Tree is linear and the edge joining the leaf nodes doesn't cross a tree edge.

<s>The simplest sufficient and generally applicable criterion is however that the set of edges that is the union of the two shortest edges, that are adjacent to a vertex, constitutes to a tour.</s>

**Edit**
there are counter examples to the criteria tha I have deleted: the instance with points $(0,0),\,(0,1),\,(1,1),\,(1,0),(1/k,1),\,\cdots,\,((k-1)/k,1)$

Comment: Thanks for thinking about my question. The MST condition is natural. Not sure about the $K_4$ idea.